# PartiQL DELETE statement using AWS SDK v3 not working

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, partiql

I have an AWS Lambda function behind API Gateway v2 that should delete an item from DynamoDB. When creating the endpoint, I based it off the AWS example code [Delete an item from a table](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/dynamodb/src/partiQL_examples/src/partiql_deleteItem.js).

The parameter substitution works for other statements, such as `SELECT` and `UPDATE`, but the `DELETE` fails to execute due to the deserializer middleware failing to format the command.

Here's my PartiQL delete statement:

```
// Create PartiQL search query to delete item
const params = {
  Statement: `DELETE FROM "${tableName}" WHERE eventId=? AND siteId=?`,
  Parameters: [{S: eventId}, {S: siteId}],
};

// Delete item from database
await ddbDocClient.send(new ExecuteStatementCommand(params));
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR   SerializationException: Start of structure or map found where not expected
at throwDefaultError (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/smithy-client/dist-cjs/default-error-handler.js:8:22)
    at de_ExecuteStatementCommandError (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:1593:51)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:7:24
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb/dist-cjs/baseCommand/DynamoDBDocumentClientCommand.js:26:34
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/middleware.js:14:20
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:7:26
    at async Runtime.handler (/var/task/src/events/endpoints/delete.js:24:9)
```

Here are the inputs I'm using:

```
{
    "Statement": "DELETE FROM \"myTable\" WHERE eventId=? AND siteId=?",
    "Parameters": [
        {
            "S": "d7b7f7fb-78c5-4d76-8b47-1316ae412de4"
        },
        {
            "S": "'test_site_1"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, if I provide only a statement with manual values fed in, it works:

```
DELETE FROM "myTable" WHERE eventId = '828474d8-982f-4955-8aed-bb8a8f373e4c' AND siteId = 'test_site_1'
```

I'm guessing that this may be an issue with the SDK's serialization middleware? Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong import

```
import {ExecuteStatementCommand} from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';
```

Instead of

```
import {ExecuteStatementCommand} from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
```